# How use domain user name without login?

Tags: mediawiki

I have a small network with 25 users with domain logins to access network resources.  I just added a MediaWiki for internal use but i don't want to require users to create a new login to use the wiki.  I do want any user to be able to edit the wiki pages.  I would like edits to be associated with their login name and not anonymous.  Is this possible?

My MediaWiki is on a Synology box and is presently [at version](https://www.synology.com/en-us/dsm/packages/MediaWiki) 1.30.  I first tried to implement LDAP but ran into problems because i'm stuck at 1.30.  But, here is the thing - **i don't care about authenticating them** - i just want MediaWiki to *associate their page edits with their username*.  Possible?

thanks,
russ

Comment: Please describe the problems you encountered with using the LDAP extension, so we could probably give you advise here. Or open another question for that :)

Comment: Will do, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is the MediaWiki supposed to know who is editing the page, without authenticating them? Authentication does not necessairly mean a set of username/password.

So, basically to your question: No, there's no way to associate an edit (or any other action in the MediaWiki software) to a specific user (= username) without authenticating them before somehow. See the [list of extensions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category:User_identity_extensions) that provide authentication mechanisms, maybe there's one you can use to authenticate users with a Synology scheme somehow (maybe OAuth, NTLM or whatever). Without any further information, I don't see how we can help here, except saying no to your question.

Comment: I'll post another question to address the LDAP problems now that i know i can't associate anonymous edits with username without login.   In brief, i installed these 3 extension (LDAPProvider, PluggableAuth, and LDAPAuthenticaton2) and added a `wfLoadExtension` for each in the LocalSettings.php file.  Then i got error messages upon opening the wiki in a browser like:   Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'LDAPProvider is not compatible with the current MediaWiki core (version 1.30.0), it requires: >= 1.31.0.

Comment: and LDAPAuthentication2 is not compatible with the current MediaWiki core (version 1.30.0), it requires: >= 1.31.0.'

Comment: Basically: MW 1.30 is already out of support for a loong time, you should upgrade to at least 1.31 or even better to the current stable release 1.34. If you can't do that, you could download at least LdapAuthentication from github for 1.30 (the 2 version is not available for this old version at all): https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-extensions-LdapAuthentication/archive/REL1_30.zip
And btw: Don't install multiple extensions that should do the same thing ;) Otherwise there might be "interesting" behaviour :P